Alternative form of Kolmogorov extension theorem on filtered space
In an thesis HERE the author proved (categorically) an alternative form of Kolmogorov extension theorem as follows (p. 129~p. 130):

let $I$ be an nonempty poset, $(\Omega,(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i\in I}, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be an filtered probability space. let $\Omega_i=(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_i)$, and suppose $\mu_i$ is a measure on $\Omega_i$ satisfiying $\mu_i\le r\mathbb{P}$ and $\forall i\le j,\mu_j|_{\mathcal{F}_i}=\mu_i$, then there exists a unique meaure $\mu$ on $\Omega$ such that $\mu|_{\mathcal{F}_i}=\mu_i$

I don't see the relationship between this and the original form. Are they equivalent? Also, shouldn't $\Omega$ be a nicer space more than just a probability space?
Moreover, the author also proved a similar form of (weaker, as he said) martingale convergence theorem:

Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be martingale w.r.t $(\mathscr{F}_i)_i$, such that $\forall i\in I, \mathbb P(X_i\le r)=1$, then there exists a unique random variable $X$ such that $\forall i\in I,\mathbb E[X|\mathscr F_i]=X_i$

I don't see where is the 'convergence' result in the version.
Any help or reference would be appreciated.

What is the nature of the index set $I$?

@John Dawkins $I$ is a poset, I'll edit my question then.

The existence of $\mu$ is a straightforward application of the Caratheodory extension theorem—the verification of countable additivity is easy because $\mu_i\le r\Bbb P$. (Lacking such a boundedness condition, one usually asks that the $\mu_i$ be inner regular, to bring some compactness into play.) I don't see that clothing the result in category-theoretical language adds much.
The connection to the usual Kolmogorov extension is as follows. One has a parameter set $T$ and wishes to construct a stochastic process $(X_t)_{\in T}$ with values in some measurable spaces $(E_t,\mathcal E_t)$ and with given finite dimensional distributions. Take $I$ to be the collection of all finite non-empty subsets of $T$ and for each $i\in I$ let $\nu_i$ be a probability measure on $(\times_{t\in i}E_t,\otimes_{t\in i}\mathcal E_t)$, such that the usual consistency conditions are  satisfied. One can then transfer these measures over to the grand product space $\Omega:=\times_{t\in T}E_t$, with $\nu_i$ mapping to $\mu_i$ defined on the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F_i$ generated by the coordinate maps $X_t:\Omega\to E_t$, $t\in i$. The consistency conditions become the restriction hypothesis $\mu_j|_{\mathcal F_i} =\mu_i$ for $i\le j$. (The elements of $I$ are ordered by inclusion.)
The "categorical limit" $X$ of the martingale $(X_i)_i\in I$, in Theorem 5.3.16, can also be obtained by standard measure theory because of the hypothesis $0\le X_i\le r$ a.s.-$\Bbb P$.

Thanks for your time. So if I understand correctly, the filtered version is a corollary of its original version and is actually weaker even if we put the boundedness condition aside? Also, what do you mean by 'grand product' (I'm not really familiar with english,sry.), is it just product of measurable spaces? btw, the author didn't mention extra condition for space $\Omega$ in his version of Kolmogorov's theorem, does that make his statement false?

The filtered version, with directed index set, is stronger than the original, which had no structure on the index set.
By grand product I simply meant $\times_{t\in T}E_t$.
The author states the "standard Borel" version of the K. extension theorem as Theorem 1.1.6, and refers on the same page (p. 16) to the famous counter-example of Andersen & Jessen showing that some conditions are necessary. The author's Theorem 5.3.17 needs no restriction on the underlying measurable spaces because of the very strong boundedness condition $\mu_i\le r\Bbb P$.
